# Stop Sprites from Pushing Each Other in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I'm coding a SpriteKit game and I'm trying to add the equivalent of a Cocos2D sensor. My problem is that my sensor keeps pushing the other sprites, but this isn't what I want. I want the sensor to be able to overlap with other sprites and not push them around. How do I fix this? Here is the code I've added for my sensor:

```
bubble.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(50))
bubble.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
bubble.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
bubble.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

And here is my collision method:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision:UInt32 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)

    if collision == (playerCategory | crateCategory) {
        NSLog("Game Over")
        var myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
        myLabel.text = "GAME OVER"
        myLabel.fontSize = 50
        myLabel.color = SKColor.blueColor()
        myLabel.position = (CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.5, self.frame.size.height*0.5))
        self.addChild(myLabel)
        fisherman.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        fisherman.removeFromParent()
        fish.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        fish.removeFromParent()
        crate.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        crate.removeFromParent()
        crateDuplicate.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        crateDuplicate.removeFromParent()


    }
    if collision == (playerCategory | bubbleCategory) {
        NSLog("Bubble Contact")
        bubbleDuplicate.removeAllActions()
        bubbleDuplicate.removeFromParent()
        bubble.removeAllActions()
        bubble.removeFromParent()
        bubbleDuplicate.setScale(0)
        bubble.setScale(0)
        bubbleDuplicate.alpha = 0


               }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `collisionBitMask` to 0, so all collisions of this particular object to others will be ignored.

Comment: @kriskendall99 you need to make object dynamic. Static objects still affect bouncing of other objects but ignores collisionBitMask.

Comment: Do you have any additional behaviors in contact delegate implemented? Contact still should happen, collision should not. How do you verify that it's still not working?

Comment: Yes, I have additional behaviors implemented. I've added a method to enable collisions with enemy sprites. I know it's not working because, when I run the game, collisions are still being made. My character sprites are able to jump on top of the sprite that's supposed to have collisions disabled.

Comment: Could you post your custom collision method as well? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood you. collisionBitMask 0 allows us to avoid collisions between objects of the same type. To ensure that other objects do not "walk over" we need to provide this Bubble unique categoryBitMask and ensure that it does not overlap collisionBitMask of other objects.

Comment: It already has a unique categoryBitMask: bubbleCategory. How do we ensure that it doesn't overlap other collsionBitMasks?

Comment: It is a bit operation bubbleCategory and target collisionBitMask should give always 0. What categories do you have? Could you write numbers here?

Comment: Sure.   let playerCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let crateCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let bubbleCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

Comment: Heh. Wish I got a prompt to start a chat, but it does not. So lets continue in comments. What about other collision masks? Could you post them too?

Comment: This are all of the masks I have:  fish.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory,  bubble.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bubbleCategory,   bubbleDuplicate.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bubbleCategory, bubbleDuplicate.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0, bubbleDuplicate.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0

Comment: Gotcha! Default collision bit mask is 0xFFFFFFFF. So no matter what is the target category, object will collide. You need to se to your fish collisionMask equal to categoryToCollide | anotherCategoryToCollide etc

Comment: If fish should not collide at all, set its collisionBitMask to 0 too.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that I just modify the code to make it so that the fish can only collide with my crate?

Comment: Each object separately decides with what he can collide. collideBitMask defines a group of objects that a collidable with object. categoryBitMask defines a specific sub-group of collidable objects in this group.

Comment: Well, I added these lines  fish.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | crateCategory
        fish.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | crateCategory and now collisions with the bubble no longer occur! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Man this was a long journey :D I am glad that I was able to help. I still have a time for your another question, see you there :)

Comment: Since answer was actually collisionBitMask, would you accept this post and discussion as answer then? Thanks

Comment: Sure. I'd be happy to do that for you.